# jQuery Alert + fancybox stacking issue

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

i have a FancyBox and a jQuery Alert, the alert is not in the same div as the fancy box.

Is there anyway i can make this alert stack above fancybox overlay? because even if i set z-index to 9999999 the alert is still behind the overlay and thus not visible enough.

http://plastiras.sait-a.gr

This is the site. If you click the gold button and then the green button on the fancybox you will see the alert under the gold button. How can i move it above the overlay?

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: set the desired z-index for `.fancybox-overlay`

Comment: .fancybox-overlay is set to 999 and fancybox-inner to 1000.

But the alert div even if is set to 999999 its still shows under it.

Comment: Why are you combining two different script when you can use fancybox for everything? It supports multiple instances starting from v3.

Comment: http://plastiras.sait-a.gr/


This is the site.

If you click the gold button and then the green button on the fancybox you will see the alert under the gold button.

How can i move it above the overlay?

Comment: Janis, the alert comes from a function that im not comfortable to edit at the moment, id prefer a css trick to make the alert visible.

Comment: you div `div#page-wrapper` z-index value is 2. that is the issue.

Comment: Thanks George! is there any way that i can make the alert div ignire the page wrapper ? because if i increase page-wrapper then the whole body gets above the fancybox overlay.